# Install boot loader in same partition as Windows Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm returning to Ubuntu after a long time. I tried it in a live USB and I decided to install it. I made my `/` partition ( is it really neccessary to make a `/home` partition? I don't intend to update any time soon). But the question is in which partition install the boot loader?

By default, the partition with the Windows boot manager, /dev/sda2, is selected but if I choose that, will Grub give me the option to Select Windows 8.1?

One time, I installed another Linux selecting the boot partition in the `/dev/sda`, and it worked well. Is that the best method?

Comment: If you have UEFI, the ESP - efi system partition is shared by all bootable systems. With either BIOS or UEFI you should specify a drive like sda, not any partition for a boot loader. Only if you install Ubuntu in BIOS and Ubuntu is in UEFI boot mode will you have troubles. Both systems must be in same boot mode to easily dual boot.